# UTF-8 String comparation returns false in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, utf-8

I have a Phonegap and I having a issue when comparing an string that is read from a file encoded as UTF-8 in sdcard and an constant stored in the program. In file I am reading "model"(UTF-8) == "model"(stored in js file) is FALSE!.
Has anyone faced a problem like this?.

Regards,

Comment: are you sure there isn't an extra white space on the UTF-8 string?

Comment: Yes, we had also trimmed each string and its the same.

Answer (score 1):

The strings cannot be exactly what you say they are. If they are indeed UTF-8, spell 'model' (pretty much fits in the ascii range) then they would be identical.

The next step I would take is just analyze both strings byte-for-byte. And when you extend your question with all the information, include the actual code and perhaps a hexdump of the data you're trying to read.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this

```
function encode_utf8( s )
{
  return unescape( encodeURIComponent( s ) );
}

function decode_utf8( s )
{
  return decodeURIComponent( escape( s ) );
}
```